# Loading more data from Database while scrolling

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to load more data when scrolling down a webpage. I found a way which calculates the scrolled space and adds the div scrolled height and then uses ajax to call a div once the Y calculated is reached, but the thing I have is I am using while then fetch which results on getting an `li` for each row on the table from the database, I thought about using the mysql `LIMIT` so I get only 10 `li` before loading more.

I know how to load another element like `div`, but I don't know how to load more from the database.

```html
<?php
                $table='posts';
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY ID desc" ;  
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Erreur SQL !'.$req.'<br>'.mysql_error());
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
    ?>

<li><section id="title"><span style=" font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:20px; ">
// a lot of other data not concerned left..
```

Comment: Can you please post your relevant code?

Comment: Hi,

Since this is something happening on the client side (the browser), you need a solution on the client side => Javascript.
First what you're looking for has a name, it's called an "Infinite Scroll", I suggest you go try looking around for some jQuery plugins that will handle the client side better than what you would do.
As for the PHP part, you will find a solution as soon as you've found an appropriate Javascript way to accomplish you objective.
Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way, and it is to make the limit a variable, i.e `SELECT * FROM $table Limit $start,$limit`
and then using ajax to manipulate those variables